# RegEx to match a term before OR after another specific term

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a squaremeter term in some kind of text using this RegExpression:

```
([0-9]{1,3}[\.|,]?[0-9]{1,2}?)\s?m\s?[qm|m\u00B2]
```

Works pretty well.

Now, this thing should only be matched if before OR after it, a string like "Wohnfläche"/"Wohnfl"/"Wfl" exists. In other words: the latter term is mandatory, however its positon is not.
Writing a RegEx for this is not the issue in general, my problem is how to write it most elegant. Currently I only see one approach:

```
^[.]*[Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl]([0-9]{1,3}[\.|,]?[0-9]{1,2}?)\s?m\s?[qm|m\u00B2]
```

new search, kombined with 'or' statement (I'm using Python)

```
([0-9]{1,3}[\.|,]?[0-9]{1,2}?)\s?m\s?[qm|m\u00B2][.]*[Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl]$
```

Ugly, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the input and desired match.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a logical conjunction in the controlling application, like (pseudo-code) `<area-regex>.match(string) and <text-regex>.match(string)`.

This assumes that any pair of matches of the two regexen on the same string will never overlap ( if they did, you'd get a false positive ). Your regexen meet this requirement.

Note that your regex for the textual context contains the additional restriction that your test string either starts or ends with a match, while in your informal description you just require a match to either occur before or after the area spec. This difference is incorporated in `pt` vs `pt_anchored` in the code below.

Python fragment (untested):

```
import re
...
# pa:          <area_regex>
# pt:          <text_regex>
# pt_anchored: <text_regex>, anchored
#
pa          = re.compile ( r'([0-9]{1,3}[\.|,]?[0-9]{1,2}?)\s?m\s?[qm|m\u00B2]' )
pt          = re.compile ( r'[.]*[Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl]' )                         
pt_anchored = re.compile ( r'^[.]*[Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl]|[.]*[Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl]$' )

if pa.match(<teststring>) and pt.match(<teststring>):
    print 'Match found: '
else:
    print 'No match'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternation like this:

```
(?:Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl)\s*(\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)\s?m\s?(qm|m\u00B2)|(\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)\s?m\s?(qm|m\u00B2)\s*(?:Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl)
```

And check which capture group matched. It is just not possible to use the restrictive strings optionally in the regex on both sides, the will just be ignored.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oX3qW6/1)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/44sEqT):

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'(?:Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl)\s*(\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)\s?m\s?(qm|m\u00B2)|(\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)\s?m\s?(qm|m\u00B2)\s*(?:Wohnfläche|Wohnfl|Wfl)')
strs = ["12,56m qm Wohnfläche", "14.54 mqm Wohnfl", "Wfl 134 m qm"]
for x in strs:
    m = pat.search(x)
    if m:
        if m.group(1): # First alternative found a match
            print("{}".format(m.group(1), " - ", m.group(2)))
        else:          # Second alternative "won"
            print("{}".format(m.group(3), " - ", m.group(4)))
```